# I cannot .load() a div that has already been .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that I have used .load() with

```
var $LoadData = $("#my-data-div");
$($LoadData).load("first-page.html");
```

I then create a table to hold some data

```
<table id="user-list">
  <tr id="tr-name1"><td>DATA</td></tr>
  <tr id="tr-name2"><td>DATA</td></tr>
  <tr id="tr-name3"><td>DATA</td></tr>
</table>
```

I then set a click handler to say everytime one of the tr's is clicked load the $LoadData DIV with a new page and pass in a url variable.

```
$("#user-list tr").on("click", function(event){
  var rowId = $(this).attr("id");
  $($LoadData).load("setStatus.asp", {sbid: rowId}, function(){
alert($($LoadData).html());
  });
});
```

My issue is the new page never loads.  The innerHTML of the $LoadData DIV is always teh same as the old page.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Update: When I check the response, status, and xhr I get a 500 internal server error.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is your click handler firing?  I.e. if you put an alert before the "var rowId =.."

Comment: Yes, I get the variable rowId to alert every time I click.

Comment: If you are getting a 500 Internal Server Error that would indicate it's your server-side code, and not your javascript. Try debugging to see where it is failing.

Comment: I have debugged all the way down to the click handler. Everything else works fine.

Comment: My server side code, the asp page, all it does is get the ID and response.write the id in the DIV then alerts the string done.

    Dim strSBNum
    strSBNum = Request.QueryString("sbid")
    response.Write(strSBNum)

Then I alert
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('DONE')
    </script>

Comment: I solved the problem. I had an extra space in my SQL statement that crapped the whole thing. UGH! I suck. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

`that` is a lambda in JavaScript.

```
$("#user-list tr")
    .on("click", function(event){
    var that = $(this)
    that
    .load("setStatus.asp",
    {sbid: rowId},
    function(){
        alert(that.html());
    });
```

});

Comment: the table is not in the div I want to load.

Comment: I solved the problem.  I had an extra space in my SQL statement that crapped the whole thing.  UGH!  I suck.  Thanks for the help guys.